# メインサイトのロゴの右端が切れている

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

左上の画像の表示がちぎれたままなのですが、私の環境が変なのでしょうか？

Comment: スプライトイメージを使っていて、幅が250pxから200pxに変更されているようですね。(多分、[BETA] 部分の幅を考慮せずに英語版のスタイルをそのまま適用されている。)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

メタと同じロゴの幅を適用しました。

> [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]