# 未ログイン状態でロゴが見切れる

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン

### 不具合事象

未ログイン状態で、幾つかのページでロゴが見切れています。

#### 正常なロゴ

[image: 正常なロゴの表示]

#### 見切れているときのロゴ

[image: 見切れているときのロゴの表示]

---

### 不具合の再現するページ

レスポンシブデザインを有効にしているか、無効にしているかで影響範囲が変化します。
また、この不具合はスタック・オーバーフロー Meta においても発生します。

#### レスポンシブデザインを無効化した場合

- すべてのページ

#### レスポンシブデザインを有効化した場合

- ユーザープロフィールページ
- ツアーページ
- タグ情報ページ
- 質問、回答の改版履歴
- 質問、回答の編集ページ

---

### 補足情報 (OS, ブラウザのバージョンなど)

不具合が再現した OS, ブラウザは以下のとおりです。

- Windows 7, 10
- Firefox 87.0
- Google Chrome 90.0.4430.93
- Opera 75.0.3969.243

---

### 暫定的な対策

[Stylus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne) などの拡張機能で以下の CSS を適用することで、ロゴの全体が表示されるようになります。

```
.-img {
    width: 184px !important;
    height: 36px !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

---

### 関連する質問

- [メインサイトのロゴの右端が切れている - スタック・オーバーフローMeta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2190/%e3%83%a1%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b5%e3%82%a4%e3%83%88%e3%81%ae%e3%83%ad%e3%82%b4%e3%81%ae%e5%8f%b3%e7%ab%af%e3%81%8c%e5%88%87%e3%82%8c%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b)
- [Site name gets cropped while looking at user profiles on international Stack Overflow sites - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316661/site-name-gets-cropped-while-looking-at-user-profiles-on-international-stack-ove)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こちらの修正が完了いたしました。未ログイン状態であっても、ページ上部にあるサイトロゴの全体が表示されるようになりました。

---

> the top bar logo
> appears in all its glory
> for anon users